# Dynamically select which subclass to inherit methods from?

Tags: python, inheritance, subclass, dynamic-programming, subclassing

Suppose I have different classes providing access to different subsystems but with a common interface. They all provide the same set of methods but each class implements them in a different way (think using foo.write() to write to a file or send data via socket, etc)

Since the interface is the same, I wanted to make a single class that is able to pick the correct class but only based on the constructor/initializer parameters.

On code, it would look like

```
class Foo(object):
    def who_am_i(self):
        print "Foo"

class Bar(object):
    def who_am_i(self):
        print "Bar"

# Class that decides which one to use and adds some methods that are common to both
class SomeClass(Foo, Bar):
    def __init__(self, use_foo):
        # How inherit methods from Foo -OR- Bar?
```

How can the `SomeClass` inherit methods from `Foo` *or* `Bar` given the `__init__` and/or `__new__` arguments?

The goal should be something like

```
>>> some_object = SomeClass(use_foo=True)
>>> some_object.who_am_i()
Foo
>>> another_object = SomeClass(use_foo=False)
>>> another_object.who_am_i()
Bar
```

Is there some clean "pythonic" way to achieve this? I didn't wanted to use a function to dynamically define `SomeClass`, but I'm not finding another way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a case for composition rather than inheritance, or maybe just a factory function that spits out either a `Foo` or a `Bar`.

Comment: Would a `SomeClass` instance either always use the methods from `Foo` or always use the methods from `Bar`, as configured at initialisation, or might it vary call to call? This is very difficult to address with such a vague example, but it seems unlikely that multiple inheritance is the correct approach.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Once an object is created, it will always use either `Foo` or `Bar`

Comment: @AndréSouto then why have you not approached this in terms of which class gets instantiated, rather than which superclass method gets called?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, this can be done with a factory function (a function that pretends to be a class):

```
def SomeClass(use_foo):
    if use_foo:
        return Foo()
    else:
        return Bar()
```

Comment: FYI a class factory would normally not be camel-cased; see e.g. `namedtuple` and `defaultdict`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I do not know what the official convention is, so I thought that since you are pretending to be a class, you could as well use the convention of a class.

Comment: Using a factory function makes `isinstance` and `issubclass` checks not work.

Comment: @ppperry how so? What would you be checking for in this case? Note that this is really an *instance* factory, so your point may not apply at all.

Comment: @ppperry: Indeed, although that's more of an argument for not pretending this thing is a class than it is an argument for using an actual class.

Comment: Don't pretend to be a class. You can't use it with isinstance, can't subclass it, etc etc. "A thing you can can call to get an object" is only a tiny part of what it is to be a class, but it's exactly what it is to be a function. Just be a function.

Comment: @Ben but the OP asked for a class.

Comment: @ppperry: And we're not giving the OP a class; we're saying that a function is a more appropriate solution to the underlying problem. Why pretend?

Comment: @ppperry I wanted to avoid the  instance factory way because of side effects I'm not aware of now that could somehow backfire in the future

Comment: @AndréSouto: The approaches involving weird inheritance structures have way more of those kinds of problems.

Comment: @AndréSouto The good thing with python is, if there are any such side effects, you can exchange it for a class again. If you find that you need that curious pattern *and* a function won’t work, you could ask another question with the added details *why* a function does not work. Or simply use one of the other suggested solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A class factory can be used here. Note the use of dictionary to make sure that the *same* subclass instance is used for each base class.

```
def makeclass(baseclass, classes={}):
    if baseclass not in classes:
        class Class(baseclass):
            pass   # define your methods here
        classes[baseclass] = Class
    return classes[baseclass]

obj1 = makeclass(Foo)(...)
obj2 = makeclass(Bar)(...)

isinstance(obj1, makeclass(Foo)) # True
isinstance(obj1, Foo)            # True
issubclass(makeclass(Foo), Foo)  # True
issubclass(type(obj1), Foo)      # True
```

You could also make a `dict` subclass with a `__missing__` method to do essentially the same thing; it makes it more explicit that you've got a container that stores classes, but creates them on demand:

```
class ClassDict(dict):
     def __missing__(self, baseclass):
         class Class(baseclass):
             pass   # define your methods here
         self[baseclass] = Class
         return Class

subclasses = ClassDict()
obj1 = subclasses[Foo]
obj2 = subclasses[Bar]
```

Comment: @ppperry instance or subclass **of what**? Again, why would that matter?

Comment: There is no parsing of a `use_foo` argument in this example. Also, there is no way using `isinstance` to say "is this either a Foo-type SomeClass or a Bar-type SomeClass?"

Comment: Adding a `use_foo` argument is trivial. Also, the `isinstance` example is in the answer: `isinstance(obj1, makeclass(Foo))`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you have your inheritance completely backwards; instead of the multiple inheritance you're proposing:

```
Foo              Bar
- foo code       - bar code

     \          /

      SomeClass(Foo, Bar)
      - common code
```

you could use a much simpler single inheritance model:

```
      SomeClass
      - common code

     /          \

Foo(SomeClass)   Bar(SomeClass)
- foo code       - bar code
```

This then makes your problem one of choosing which subclass to instantiate (a decision that only needs to be made once) rather than which superclass method to call (which potentially needs to be made on every method call). This could be solved with as little as:

```
thing = Foo() if use_foo else Bar()
```

Comment: What is there is an additional `Base` class which both `Foo` and `Bar` are subclasses of, producing a diamond inheritance pattern in which this selective inheritance is necessary.

Comment: @ppperry then if that turns out to be the case I may need to revise the answer, but there's no sign of that so far and I'd happily err on the side of suggesting the simpler thing first...

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the lack of agreement upon the answer, maybe the problem is the question. [jonrsharpe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212728/dynamically-select-which-subclass-to-inherit-methods-from#comment58140998_35212728) gave an interesting insight on the problem: this should **not** be solved via inheritance.

Consider `SomeClass` defined as follows:

```
# Class that uses Foo or Bar depending on the environment
# Notice it doesn't subclasses either Foo or Bar
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, use_foo):
        if use_foo:
            self.handler = Foo() 
        else:
            self.handler = Bar() 

    # Makes more sense asking 'Who implements?' instead of 'Who am I?'
    def who_implements(self):
        return self.handler

    # Explicitly expose methods from the handler
    def some_handler_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.handler.some_handler_method(*args, **kwargs)

    def another_handler_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.handler.another_handler_method(*args, **kwargs)
```

Should we need to get details on the handler implementation, just get the `handler` attribute. Other classes that subclass `SomeClass` won't even see the handler directly, which actually makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

One could use a `__new__` method for this purpose:

```
_foos = {}
_bars = {}
class SomeClass(object):
     def __new__(cls,use_foo,*args,**kwargs):
         if use_foo:
            if cls not in _foos:
                class specialized(cls,Foo):pass
                _foos[cls] = specialized
           else:
               specialized = _foos[cls]
         else:
            if cls not in _bars:
                class specialized(cls,Bar):pass
                _bars[cls] = specialized
           else:
               specialized = _bars[cls]
         specialized.__name__ = cls.__name__
         return object.__new__(specialized,*args,**kwargs)
     #common methods to both go here
     pass
```

The advantage of this over a factory function is that `isinstance(SomeClass(True),SomeClass)` works, and that `SomeClass` can be subclassed.

Comment: It's not clear to me how your advantages are sufficiently advantageous to justify the complexity that this adds. Given that Python code is primarily duck-typed, supporting the appropriate interface is often all that matters.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is an actual class, rather an factory function. Therefore, `isinstance` and `issubclass` checks work etc.

Comment: ...again, so what? Even if that was important, the class returned by a class factory (which isn't really what the other answers suggest anyway) could also define superclasses using e.g. `type(name, bases, dict)` and would be indistinguishable from those created statically.

Comment: In the class factory approach, there is no easy way to say "is this object belonging to a class created in the class factory". `isinstance` and `issubclass` allow that kind of checking easily.

Comment: Please stop just repeating that and explain *why you think that would matter*. Are you used to languages less dynamic than Python?

Comment: If we're going to pick on whether the solution preserves things like `isinstance` and `issubclass`, it's worth noting that with this solution every single object created by `SomeClass(...)` will now be an instance of its own freshly-created class. Whether any of this matters at all is a matter for the OP's use case, not something that can be decided by a general rule.

Comment: The factory functions work *fine* with `issubclass` and `isinstance` when properly implemented. Saying "there is no easy way to say 'is this object belonging to a class created in the class factory`" is simply false.